# XmlHTTPRequest and 301 redirects

Tags: security, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

Do any browsers follow cross-domain 301 redirects when processing XmlHTTPRequests (or any other method a page can get the contents of another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't use a 301 to work around the same origin policy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup a [cross-domain proxy](http://ajaxpatterns.org/archive/Cross-Domain_Proxy.php),  and one should exist for your web application platform.  These are commonly used by social networks to bypass the [same-origin policy](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2).